# window.confirm message not working when user disables additional dialogue from the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, confirm

I am new to java script. And now have gone into a really serious problem.
Please help..................! stackoverflow

I have one jsp page for deleting entries. where user can delete data. As soon as he clicks delete button , he gets a confirmation window saying "Are you sure you want to delete..?". Problem is when user deletes 4,5 entries he gets an alert from the browser saying " [*] Prevent this page from creating additional dialogues." when user clicks the checkbox and prevents himself  getting additional dialogues.  my confirmation message "Are you sure you want to delete?" also gets blocked and user is unable to delete the data and the whole portal becomes useless.

please help me and let me know is there any way to handle that using javascript.

Comment: You should use a custom alert box instead of the window one. That behaviour is managed by the browser and there's no way to prevent that as far as I know.

Comment: Like @BeNdErR says: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Comment: Is there a way to disable that. PREVENT... message

Answer (score 0):

Browser alerts are little irritating. Create your custom popup or use Jquery popup. You cannot control browser alerts behaviour

Answer (score -1):

You can use one of the best plugin for alerts and confirm dialogs
http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/

Comment: Ankit am using struts so right now havent planned to move to bootstrap

Comment: @piyushkumar, then we can not change browser behavior for alerts, you have to use some jquery customized alert or customization